How to find existing life insurance where I might be the beneficiary?
My wife's parents died within a few months of each other early in 2023.  There was not much of an estate but my wife received a modest check from a life insurance policy shortly after the second parent's death.  Yesterday she received a call from New York Life saying that she is the beneficiary on yet another modest policy (the one last year was not NYL).  (The call from NYL was legit, not a scam).  That got her wondering if there might be other policies out there with other companies that she just does not know about.  Is there a centralized place to ask "Am I the bene on any life insurance policy for my parents?" instead of waiting for companies to track her down or worse, "watching", for years, the state unclaimed property office of the two states where he parents lived shortly before death?

This question seems more appropriate for [money.se], it's not a legal issue.

Cross posted on money@se

Found it ourselves.  Sharing here for others.
https://eapps.naic.org/life-policy-locator/#/decedent
This is the NAIC (National Association of Insurance Commissioners) web site that allows you to submit a request. You have to identify yourself and provide contact info. You need particulars about the deceased as well, name, dt of birth, dt of death, SSN. It can take several months for them to reply and they only reply IF a company replies to them that there is a policy. So, if you don’t hear from them you don’t know if it is because they are “still looking” or if they are done but did not find anything.

You should accept the answer to mark this question solved.
